# Multivariable function having partial derivatives almost everywhere are necessarily measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, partial-derivative, measurable-functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that partial derivatives
\begin{equation}
(\partial_i f)(x) := \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h e_i)-f(x)}{h}
\end{equation}
exists for all $i=1,\cdots,n$ and almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then I wonder if $f$ itself is Lebesgue-measurable on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here, $n \geq 2$ is arbitrary.

Could anyone please help me? I think it is true at least for $n=2$ but cannot generalize further.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry for not being specific. $n$ here is "fixed".

Comment: @geetha290krm Ok. But we do not know measurability of $f$ or $\partial_i f$ in advance?

Comment: Even though the existence of partials doesn't necessarily give you continuity everywhere, I wonder how big the set of discontinuities can be?  If it's null, then you'd have your measurability.

I've only seen constructive counter-examples to [partials imply continuity] with null sets of discontinuity.  But I don't know if a small discontinuity set necessarily follows from the existence of the partials or if that's a coincidental feature of the typical counter-examples.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but is it even true for $n = 1$? That is, if a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ admits a derivative almost everywhere, does $f$ have to be measurable?

Comment: @BrunoB I guess so. Indeed, let $X$ be the set of real $x$ such that $f'(x)$ exists. Then $\mathbb R\setminus X$ has measure $0$ and $f|X$ is continuous. Let $U$ be any open subset of $\mathbb R$. Then there exists an open subset $U'$ of $\mathbb R $ such that $f^{-1}(U)\cap X=U'\cap X$. So $f^{-1}(U)=(U'\cup (\mathbb R\setminus X))\setminus Y$ for some subset $Y$ of $\mathbb R$ of zero measure. I expect this implies that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: By the way, by $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable you mean that $f^{-1}(X)$ is Lebesgue measurable for each Borel subset $X$ of $\mathbb R$ or for each Lebesgue-measurable subset $X$ of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @AlexRavsky I believe the convention is $X\subset {\mathbb R}$ is a Borel set. (Otherwise even continuous functions may not be measurable.)

Answer (score 8):

Even more general result is true:

**Theorem.** A function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is Lebesgue measurable if $f$ is separately continuous almost everwhere.

*Proof.* This theorem can be proved by induction on $n$. For $n=1$, $f$ is continuous almost everywhere, which means that there exists a Lebesgue null set $N\subseteq \mathbb R$ such that $f{\restriction}_{\mathbb R\setminus N}$ is continuous and hence $f$ is Lebesue measurable.

Assume that the theorem is proved for some $n$. Take any function $f:\mathbb R^{n+1}\to\mathbb R$ which is separately continuous almost everywhere. Then there exists a Lebesgue null set $N\subseteq\mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that for every $x\in \mathbb R^{n+1}\setminus N$ and every $i\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ we have $f(x)=\lim_{\delta\to 0}f(x+\delta e_i)$. Identify the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with the product $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R$. By the Fubini Theorem, there exists a null set $M\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that for every $q\in\mathbb R\setminus M$ the set $N_q=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:(x,q)\in N\}$ is Lebesgue-null in $\mathbb R^n$. Choose any countable dense set $Q\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus M$ and consider the Lebesgue null set $N_Q=\bigcup_{q\in Q}N_q$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Then the set $\tilde N=N\cup(N_Q\times\mathbb R)$ is Lebesgue-null in $\mathbb R^{n+1}=\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R$. By the inductive assumption, for every $q\in Q$, the function $f_q:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, $f_q:x\mapsto f(x,q)$, is Lebesgue measurable.

To prove that the function $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable, we have to show that for every real numbers $a<b$, the set $f^{-1}(a,b)=\{x\in\mathbb R^{n+1}:a<f(x)<b\}$ is Lebesgue measurable. Since the set $\tilde N=N\cup(N_Q\times \mathbb R)$ is Lebesgue null, it suffices to check that the set $f^{-1}(a,b)\setminus \tilde N$ is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. For every $x\in f^{-1}(a,b)\setminus \tilde N$, the separate continuity of $f$ at $x$ ensures that $f(x)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}f(x+\varepsilon e_{n+1})$. Then the set
$$\begin{aligned}
f^{-1}(a,b)\setminus \tilde N&=\{(x,y)\in (\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R)\setminus \tilde N:\\
&\quad\quad\exists k\in\mathbb N\;\forall m\in\mathbb N\;\exists q\in Q\;\;
|y-q|<\tfrac1m\;\wedge\; a+\tfrac1k\le f(x,q)\le b-\tfrac1k\}\\
&=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{m\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{q\in Q}\{(x,y)\in(\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R)\setminus\tilde N:|y-q|<\tfrac1m\;\wedge\;
 a+\tfrac1k\le f_q(x)\le b-\tfrac1k\} 
\end{aligned}
$$
is Lebesgues measurable by the Lebesgue measurability of the functions $f_q$.$\quad\square$

Comment: I was ready to give up on the continuity approach since we didn’t have joint continuity. Didn’t occur to me to just use separate continuity. Good call. Cheers!

Comment: @JoshKeneda Thanks!